# Amazon instance store is restartable?

Tags: amazon-instance-store

I am running an instance backed by instance store, I know If I stop the instance it will be no longer available but can I restart that instance? I can see an option on amazon console when I right click on the Amazon instance store but I am not sure about that.

here is the answer but they did not mention if we restart the instance it will be no longer available.
http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#What_is_the_difference_between_using_the_local_instance_store_and_Amazon_Elastic_Block_storage_for_the_root_device

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [RebootInstances](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-RebootInstances.html) API call to reboot an instance. Instances using the instance store will not lose the data stored on disk. In the AWS Management Console this is labelled "Reboot" under "Instance Actions".

Comment: Thanks, You are right, reboot will not effect any data if the server is not effected by something else.

Comment: By the way I restarted my server, I got nothing. On the Amazon console I am getting "No Data", so Just a recommendation keep the clone of the server as a backup, in case the server does not come up you can switch over the IP to the server.

Comment: Got the Following from Amazon now, they are saying our hardware was not recoverable.